JavaScript Focus Ring Option Is Not Working
I'm using the code below to set focus to a button and have a focus ring displayed around the button. While the button does indeed get focus (which I can tell because if I press the space bar the button's onclick event fires), the focus ring does not display (unless I manually tab to the button).
Thinking I was doing something wrong, I checked the example used in mdn web docs, and sure enough, it doesn't work there either! (Scroll down to the JavaScript section and click play and you'll see what I mean.)
Since I am using the latest and greatest version of Chrome for Windows, does that mean the focusVisible option is no longer supported? Or am I doing something wrong?
My code:
document.getElementById("myButton").focus({ focusVisible: true });

I don't see any issue with the code. https://jsbin.com/deqiruyamu/edit?html,js,output

@underscore It works when the call is at top-level, but not when it's in a click event listener. Maybe focus is staying on the button that was clicked?

@uderscore, as I indicated, focus is moving to the correct button but the focus ring is not displayed.

@userscore, I'm not sure where the code would be if not in the event listener of the button initiating the code. Did you try the mdn web docs example? Doesn't seem to be working there either.

My bad for not checking the browser compatibility table in the mdn web docs. It turns out, what I want to do is supported only on Firefox. On Chrome, you can programtically change focus to another button, but without a visible indication you have done so! Come on, Chrome. Get with it!
